# Separate "Mr John Joe Smith" into "Mr" "John" "Joe" "Smith"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A file supplied by a Client has the following structure:

| FullName |
| --- |
| Mr John Joe Smith |

They would like this transformed to the following:

| Salutation | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mr | John | Joe | Smith |

I've looked into this and I've tried the following:

```sql
SELECT        substring(FullName,0,charindex(' ',Fullname)) As Salutation, substring(FullName,charindex(' ',Fullname)+1,len(fullname)) As FirstName
FROM            dbo.Individuals
```

This produces:

| Salutation | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| Mr | John Joe Smith |

I'm struggling to separate it further, is this the best way of doing it or is there a better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Required Reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: The short answer is "you don't". If you didn't separate this at the time of entry, then you have no idea what is a true first name, middle name, or surname.

Comment: You have no idea the can of worms you're trying to open.

Comment: Have you searched for "string split"?  Do any of the results work for you?

Comment: What will you do for `Mr John & Mrs Joanne Jones Smith Esq.`?

Comment: Have you never met John Esq. @Charlieface ? They like to go by their first middle name though, "ampersand", but some of his friends call him "Mrs" to annoy him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there's always the same four elements in the same order...

```
select  parsename(replace('Mr John Joe Smith',' ','.'),4) [Salutation],
        parsename(replace('Mr John Joe Smith',' ','.'),3) [FirstName],
        parsename(replace('Mr John Joe Smith',' ','.'),2) [MiddleName],
        parsename(replace('Mr John Joe Smith',' ','.'),1) [LastName]
```

Comment: This will work nicely with any string that already contains a period, e.g. `'Dr. Ludwig Philipp Albert Schweitzer'`. Note that [`ParseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) tends to fail silently when presented with unexpected input, e.g. `select ParseName( 'Dr..Ludwig.Philipp.Albert.Schweitzer', 1 );`.

Comment: That's very true.

Comment: Of course, that really applies to any potential solution for this.  If you start with unclean data, there's never any guarantees of the result, unless you build in a series of data cleansing.

Comment: There's a difference between splitting the string into four columns based on the first three blanks and letting all of the excess land in the `LastName` column vs. introducing a new problem by splitting on a different character that may or may not be present already and returning `null` for all of the columns. Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names explains a wide range of additional options for failure.

Comment: Thanks @WAMLeslie, this is working well. I can see in the results it's producing the desired effect. I can also see when a person has more than 3 names it returns null for that row. This is probably a discussion with the client about design rather than a logic issue. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Stuart Glad it worked for you.  And yes, starting with clean data is always the best way to go with it when possible.  If you have a chance, please accept the answer if this is the one you're going with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to parsename:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT FullName,Name
   ,CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN 'Salutation' WHEN 2 THEN 'FirstName' WHEN 3 THEN 'MiddleName' WHEN 4 THEN 'LastName' END AS ColName
  FROM (SELECT FullName,value AS Name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FullName ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Individuals
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(FullName,' ') ) base ) mid
PIVOT (MAX(Name) FOR ColName IN ([Salutation],[FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName]) ) p
```

You could expand the CASE statement to make it less format-sensitive. For example:

```
CASE
 WHEN FullName LIKE '% % % %' THEN
  CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN 'Salutation' WHEN 2 THEN 'FirstName' WHEN 3 THEN 'MiddleName' WHEN 4 THEN 'LastName' END
 WHEN FullName LIKE '% % %' THEN
  CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN 'FirstName' WHEN 2 THEN 'MiddleName' WHEN 3 THEN 'LastName' END
 WHEN FullName LIKE '% %' THEN
  CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN 'FirstName' WHEN 2 THEN 'LastName' END
END AS ColName
```

But this would still backfire and need additional logic if you have a mix of "Mr John Smith"s and "John Joe Smith"s, lines with more than 5 components, etc.

STRING_SPLIT also doesn't have a guaranteed return order according to the documentation, though I've never personally seen it differ from the original string's order. You could [define your own](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) function if you need guaranteed ordering, or if you're on pre-compatibility-130 and don't have STRING_SPLIT.